# error con incompatible cannot convertir a bolean y en operador &&

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

package buscaminas;

```
public class MatrizMinas {

    //atributos
    private int valores[][];

    //constructor

    public MatrizMinas(){
        valores = new int [10][10];
        limpiarMinas();
    }
    //limpiar la pantalla
    public void limpiarMinas(){

        for (int m = 0; m < 10; m++){
            for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++){
                valores[m][n] = 0;

            }
        }
    }

    //insertar aleatoriamente las minas 
    public void ponerMinas(){
        limpiarMinas();

        int m;
        int n;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            do{
                m = (int) (Math.random() * 10) ;
                n = (int) (Math.random() * 10) ;
            ***}while (valores[m][n] ! = 0);***
            valores [m][n] = 9;
        }


    }

    //devolver el valor de la casilla 
    public int getMina (int m, int n){
        return valores [m][n];
    }

    //calcular contorno de la mina
    public void calcularContornos(){
        for (int m = 0; m < 10; m++){
            for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++){
                if (valores[m][n] = 9){
                    for (int m2 = m - 1; m2 <= m + 1; m2++){
                        for (int n2 = n - 1; n2 <= n + 1; n2++){
                            ***if (m2 >=0 && m2 < 10 && n2 >= 0 && n2 < 10 && valores [m][n]){***
                                valores[m2][n2]++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: necesito insertar aleatoriamente las minas y me sale ese error ayuda

Comment: Hola @bryan eso que acabas de poner en el comentario agregalo a tu pregunta de otro modo solo tu sabes que es lo que ocurre

Answer (score 2):

Tienes dos problemas de sintaxis; el primero de ellos y el que enmarcas en la pregunta:

```
if (m2 >=0 && m2 < 10 && n2 >= 0 && n2 < 10 && valores [m][n] ??)
```

Los operadores l'ogicos trabajan sobre valores booleanos, en `valores [m][n]` estas retornando un entero, debes compararlo con algo.
El otro error que tienes es en el `do while` en `ponerMinas`, la condición de parada del ciclo `while (valores[m][n] ! = 0)`, el comparador `!=` no debe llevar espacios entre sí, quedando:

```
while (valores[m][n] != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Al final de tu if pones valores [m][n] lo cual es un entero, no un booleano por eso es tu error.

Se declaró:

```
private int valores [][];
valores = new int [10] [10];
```

Lo cual es una matriz de enteros, por lo que en tu código pones al final del if lo siguiente

```
if (m2 >=0 
    && m2 < 10 
    && n2 >= 0 
    && n2 < 10
    && valores [m][n]){// aquí está tu error valores como explicó arriba es un entero no un booleano
    //Logica
}
```

Comment: no me queda claro tu solución pudieras explicarla mejor?